# Android Copying row from one SQL table to another

Tags: android, mysql, sql, database, sqlite

In my application I'm attempting to copy one row from my first database to my second using and ID as reference for which ones I would like to be copied. The current code below shows my SQL method but it doesn't seem to be working, is my syntax wrong.

```
public void insertAlarmContacts(String id)
{

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO alarm_contact_list SELECT * FROM contact_list WHERE grouped_contacts =" + id);


}
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with Android thingy so I'll just ask you about the database related concern. When you say not working not working because its not copying the record? or do you receive an error? If you are not receiving any error then maybe the select statement does not return any records? What is the data type of grouped_contacts? Anyway it is safe to put single quote in WHERE Clause in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You must use like `"'" + id + "'"` because id is `String` , if `id` is `int` then your code is ok ..